# qt convert mouse position to chart coordinate system

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I would like to display a [callout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-callout-example.html) on a QChart with a QBarSeries displayed. 
I'm struggling in how to convert the position of my mouse to the qchart coordinate frame, so that I can use it as Anchor in my callout. 
I would like to set it during my

```
MainWindow::barSeriesHovered(bool status, int index, QBarSet *barset){}
```

event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it using following code:

```
auto point = QCursor::pos();
point = myChartView->mapFromGlobal(point);
auto pointF = myChartView->mapToScene(point);
pointF = myChartView->chart()->mapFromScene(point);
pointF = myChartView->chart()->mapToValue(point,myChartView->chart()->series().at(0));
myCallout->setAnchor(pointF);
```

maybe not the most efficient use, but yes, it works
Another drawback is, that it always appears at the border of a bar, and does not move with your mouse cursor while you move around inside the bar, but yes, it works